# How to fetch last argument and stop before last arguments in shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, sh, csh, subshell

I want to merge all files into one. Here, the last argument is the destination file name.
I want to take last argument and then in loop stop before last arguments.

Here code is given that I want to implement:

```
echo "No. of Argument : $#"
for i in $* - 1
do
   echo $i
   cat $i >> last argument(file)
done
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: Note that it would be a lot easier if the target file was listed first and the source files afterwards.  You'd have: `target="$1"; shift; cat "$@" > "$target"` and it would not rely on Bash.  The GNU commands [`mv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) and [`cp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp) have been modified to support an option `-t destination` to specify a destination directory, which is similar to what I propose.

Comment: yeah it is one of the good logic... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `bash`:

```
fname=${!#}
for a in "${@:1:$# - 1}"
do
    echo "$a"
    cat "$a" >>"$fname"
done
```

In `bash`, the last argument to a script is `${!#}`.  So, that is where we get the file name.

`bash` also allows selecting elements from an array.  To start with a simple example, observe:

```
$ set -- a b c d e f
$ echo "${@}"
a b c d e f
$  echo "${@:2:4}"
b c d e
```

In our case, we want to select elements from the first to the second to last.  The first is number `1`.  The last is number `$#`.  We want to select all but the last.  WE thus want `$# - 1` elements of the array.  Therefore, to select the arguments from the first to the second to last, we use:

```
${@:1:$# - 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

A POSIX-compliant method:

```
eval last_arg=\$$#
while [ $# -ne 1 ]; do
    echo "$1"
    cat "$1" >> "$last_arg"
    shift
done
```

Here, `eval` is safe, because you are only expanding a read-only parameter in the string that `eval` will execute. If you don't want to unset the positional parameters via `shift`, you can iterate over them, using a counter to break out of the loop early.

```
eval last_arg=\$$#
i=1
for arg in "$@"; do
    echo "$arg"
    cat "$arg" >> "$last_arg"
    i=$((i+1))
    if [ "$i" = "$#" ]; then
        break
    fi
 done
```